# Errors when uploading images in WP 3.5

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails, media

I'm trying to upload images in WP 3.5 to set featured images for posts. Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

The installed theme is Minimatica. I've tried Googling the issue, but couldn't find any solution except downgrade to WP 3.4.2.

Comment: Also, if someone knows how to get a detailed log about this error, please let me know.

Comment: [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). If you have access to server logs that would be quite helpful.

Comment: It's a shared hosting account, I doubt I have access to the logs.

Comment: You can enable the debugging though.

Comment: With WP_DEBUG turned on you'll have errors and notices printed on the front end. You may not have access to the logs, but you can always tell it to log somewhere you **do** have access to via htaccess/wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

This was addressed on the Minimatica website:

http://www.onedesigns.com/support/topic/how-to-fix-issues-with-media-uploader-with-minimatica-in-wordpress-3-5

You will need to update your functions.php file as follows:

In functions.php find this line (line 225 if you haven’t altered the file):

```
add_action('init', 'minimatica_register_styles');
```

and replace it  with --

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'minimatica_register_styles');
```

**AND**

Then find this line (line 437 if you haven’t altered the file):

```
add_filter( 'ext2type', 'minimatica_mime_types' );
```

which you will replace with --

```
add_filter( 'ext2type', 'minimatica_file_types' );
```

After making the necessary changes, save your functions.php file. If you altered the file offline, upload the saved functions.php file to the wp-content>>themes>>minimatica theme folder. Refresh your new post screen and you should be good to go.  This worked perfectly for me so hopefully will for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

Try to add this code to your wp-config.php file, just before the require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php'); string.

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```